Where does chrome extension saves inputs of the user?
I am using Seleniumbase UC mode to make a undetected automation. I used multiple ways of hiding my bot and one of them is HTTP headers. I couldn't find any solution for it that could be integrated in seleniumbase so I used extension for that: https://mybrowseraddon.com/modify-header-value.html
Extension UI
Now i can change the Header value trough extension and it works with my bot, but i for every use i will have to rotate the user header (Sometimes i will need windows while other times i will need android platform). Now the "Simple" solution is to just edit those values with my bot manually (Before bot enter the page, it will first go to the extension UI and manually import the headers). This soulution in not the best but only one i have.
Now i wanted to know if i can somehow change the data in the plugins file so the right HTTP headers are activated at the beginning right when the browsers is activated. For that i need to find where that data is stored but I cant find it. Is it in cloud. Can I even change like that. (Check at the bottom of image to see the inputs)
I found the path to the extension (It is copied in my path of the script) and there are these files:
extension directory
01/01/1980  02:00 AM               170 background.js
04/07/2024  01:00 PM    <DIR>          data
04/07/2024  01:00 PM    <DIR>          lib
04/07/2024  12:52 PM             1,629 manifest.json

data directory:
04/07/2024  01:00 PM    <DIR>          icons
04/07/2024  01:00 PM    <DIR>          options
04/07/2024  01:00 PM    <DIR>          popup

lib directory:
01/01/1980  02:00 AM             6,563 chrome.js
01/01/1980  02:00 AM             3,592 common.js
01/01/1980  02:00 AM               611 config.js
01/01/1980  02:00 AM             7,002 netrequest.js
01/01/1980  02:00 AM             3,348 runtime.js

Cant find anything resembling the data that i inouted trough extension

"rotate the user header" -- do you mean the User-Agent header?

What do you mean by "data in the plugins file"?

It's stored in the browser data directory.

@Barmar: I maent HTTP header. On of the thing in http header is the user agent, but i can change that without intercepting http header

@Barmar: Example in the picture. I inputed data in the inputs like the url, header i want to change and value of header. That data is saved and stay there when the new browser session is opened (Browser starting again)
